# Setting the same distance from the top of the page for chapter and index titles

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, chapters, indexing, two-column

I noticed that the distance from the top of the page to the chapter title differs from the table of contents and list of `<>` ones. I can see why, as these elements have specific purposes and semantics in a document:

[image: My explanation]

I have a document in which this distance should be the very same, for project reasons. The following code refers to the previous image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[useindex]{splitidx}
\newindex[List of Foo]{iof}
\makeindex

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Bar}

Hi there\sindex[iof]{Bar}

\chapter*{Foo}

Hi there\sindex[iof]{Foo}

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

Chapters could have the same distance of the table of contents / lists of `<>` or vice versa. I'm stuck with this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I also noticed that different line spacing with the `setspace` changes the upper margin :-(. I normally use `\singlespacing` for ToC etc. but need to have larger spacing for the main content of my thesis.

Comment: @Martin: I didn't noticed that! Thanks for mentioning it. `=)`

Comment: @Paulo: I changed the question title because an index is not a ToC.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks, it looks way better now. `=)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have stumbled upon [LaTeX bug 3126](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=latex/3126&introduction=yes&state=open) (`\twocolumn` interfering with `\topskip`). Load my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package (which uses `multicol`) to avoid the bug.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Foo}

Hi there!\index{Foo}

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, lockstep! I'll read the `idxlayout` documentation, seems very interesting.

Comment: In **imakeidx** we redefine `theindex` to use `multicols` so the problem doesn't show.

Comment: @egreg: The same is true for `idxlayout`.

Comment: I should have known. Of course this has the advantage that the final page has balanced columns.