# Wrong vertical position of heading created by \printindex

Tags: sectioning, vertical-alignment, indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the same distance from the top of the page for chapter and index titles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23287/setting-the-same-distance-from-the-top-of-the-page-for-chapter-and-index-titles)

When compiling the following example, you can see that the heading heading "Index" (created by `\printindex`) has a different vertical position than the first two headings.

Strangely, it gets better when you comment out the line `\KOMAoption{open}{right}` although the positioning is still different.

What is the reason for this behavior and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{open}{right}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex


\begin{document}

  \chapter{First Test}
  \chapter{Second Test}
  \index{test}
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a bit older version of TeXLive and really old versions of KOMA-script. Anyways, the word "Index" is a bit lower on the page than "2 Second Test", even without `\KOMAoption{open}{right}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index is set in `twocolumn` mode, and `\twocolumn` interferes with `\topskip` (LaTeX bug 3126). One solution is to load my [`idxlayout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/idxlayout) package which uses [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) instead.

(Note: In the process of answering this question, I stumbled upon what seems to be an incompatibility between `idxlayout` and v3.10a of the `KOMA-Script` classes -- the automatic loading of the [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package fails. As a workaround, you have to load `ragged2e` manually.)

EDIT: `idxlayout` v0.4d, which fixes the mentioned incompatibility, is on its way to CTAN.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\KOMAoption{open}{right}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{First Test}
  \chapter{Second Test}
  \index{test}
  \printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: using your `idxlayout` package solved the problem - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug related to the command `\twocolumn`. If you load the `imakeidx` package instead of `makeidx`, the `theindex` environment will be redefined without `\twocolumn` and the problem disappears.

Comment: Using `imakeidx` worked for me and it also results in a correct vertical alignment of the heading. However, the space inserted between the heading and the first index entry differs from the space between a standard chapter heading and the first line of the following paragraph. That effect didn't show up when using `idxlayout` therefore I accepted lockstep's answer.

Comment: @boothby81 `idxlayout` sets `\multicolsep` to 0pt within the `theindex` environment.